# Ruby - Finding the longest palindromic substring in a string

Tags: ruby, string, substring, reverse, palindrome

I understand how to find if one string is a palindrome

```
string1 == string1.reverse
```

It's a little more difficult though with multiple palindromes in a string

```
"abcdxyzyxabcdaaa"
```

In the above string, there are 4 palindromes of length greater than 1

```
"xyzyx", "yzy", "aaa" and "aa"
```

In this case, the longest palindrome is "xyxyx", which is 5 characters long.

How would I go about solving this problem though.

I know of the array#combination method, but that won't work in this case.

I was thinking of implementing something like this

```
def longest_palindrome(string)
  palindromes = []
  for i in 2..string.length-1
    string.chars.each_cons(i).each {|x|palindromes.push(x) if x == x.reverse}
  end
  palindromes.map(&:join).max_by(&:length)
end
```

Comment: You would need to implement something like the Manacher's algorithm to solve this problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring

Comment: You don't _need_ to use a fancy linear time algorithm. It would be easier (and perhaps sufficient) to use a naive O(n^2) algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your just looking for the largest palindrome substring, Here is a quick and dirty solution.

```
def longest_palindrome(string, size)
  string.size.times do |start| # loop over the size of the string
    break if start + size > string.size # bounds check

    reverse = string[start, size].reverse

    if string.include? reverse #look for palindrome
      return reverse #return the largest palindrome
    end
  end
  longest_palindrome(string, size - 1) # Palindrome not found, lets look for the next smallest size 
end
```

Comment: Excellent and well-thought out solution. That will work.

Comment: This is incorrect - `longest_palindrome('abcdefghba', 10)` returns `'ba'` which is not true. The inclusion condition is not enough.

Comment: You are missing the actual check for a palindrome... 
`if string[start, size].reverse == string[start, size]`

Answer (score 2):

```
def longest_palindrome(string)
  longest = ''
  i = 0
  while i < string.length
    j = 1
    while (i + j) <= string.length
      x = string.slice(i, j)
      if (x.length > longest.length) && (x == x.reverse)
        longest = x
      end
      j += 1
    end
    i += 1
  end
  longest
end
```

The slice method is handy to have for solving this problem. Test each substring with the classic double while loop approach with `(i, j)` representing a starting index and length of the substring respectively. `string.slice(start_index, substring_length)`

The String#slice method works like this:

```
"bdehannahc".slice(3, 8) == "hannah" # which is a palindrome and would be 
                                     # found by the method introduced above
```

Answer (score 1):

This checks if the entire string `str` is a palindrome. If it is, we're finished; if not, check all substrings of length `str.size-1`. If one is a palindrome, we're finished; if not, check substrings of length `str.size-1`, and so on.

```
def longest_palindrome(str)
  arr = str.downcase.chars
  str.length.downto(1) do |n|
    ana = arr.each_cons(n).find { |b| b == b.reverse }
    return ana.join if ana
  end
end

longest_palindrome "abcdxyzyxabcdaaa"
  #=> "xyzyx"
longest_palindrome "abcdefghba"
  #=> "a"
```

The key method here is [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons).

Comment: This works great but we don't need `.downcase`

Answer (score 1):

Longest Palindromic Substring : **Ruby O(n)** solution by [**Manacher's Algorithm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring)

Attached **Benchmark**

```
# @param {String} s
# @return {String}
def longest_palindrome(s)
  return "" if s.empty?

  chars = s.chars.zip(s.size.times.map { "|" }).flatten.unshift("|")
  n = chars.size

  p_len = Array.new(3, n)
  p_len[0] = 0
  p_len[1] = 1

  max_len, max_len_pos = 0, 0

  center = 1
  right = 2

  2.step(n - 1).each do |i|   # want to use enumerator; n.times.drop(2) makes (n-2) length array
    mirror = 2 * center - i
    diff = right - i

    expand = false

    if 0 < diff
      len = p_len[mirror]

      if len < diff
        p_len[i] = len

      elsif len == diff && i == n - 1
        p_len[i] = len

      elsif len == diff && i < n - 1
        p_len[i] = len
        expand = true

      elsif diff < len
        p_len[i] = diff
        expand = true

      end
    else
      p_len[i] = 0
      expand = true
    end

    if expand
      while (i + p_len[i]) < n && 0 < (i - p_len[i]) && (not_boundary_char(p_len, i) || same_char?(chars, p_len, i))
        p_len[i] += 1
      end
    end

    if max_len < p_len[i]
      max_len = p_len[i]
      max_len_pos = i
    end

    if i < i + p_len[i]
      center = i
      right = i + p_len[i]
    end
  end

  first = (max_len_pos - max_len) / 2
  last = first + max_len - 1
  s[first..last]
end

def not_boundary_char(p_len, i)
  (i + p_len[i] + 1) % 2 == 0
end

def same_char?(chars, p_len, i)
  chars[i - p_len[i] - 1] == chars[i + p_len[i] + 1]
end

def longest_palindrome1(s)
  arr = s.chars
  s.length.downto(1) do |n|
    ana = arr.each_cons(n).find { |b| b == b.reverse }
    return ana.join if ana
  end
end

# ********************#
#     Benchmark       #
# ********************#

require "benchmark"

s = "anugnxshgonmqydttcvmtsoaprxnhpmpovdolbidqiyqubirkvhwppcdyeouvgedccipsvnobrccbndzjdbgxkzdbcjsjjovnhpnbkurxqfupiprpbiwqdnwaqvjbqoaqzkqgdxkfczdkznqxvupdmnyiidqpnbvgjraszbvvztpapxmomnghfaywkzlrupvjpcvascgvstqmvuveiiixjmdofdwyvhgkydrnfuojhzulhobyhtsxmcovwmamjwljioevhafdlpjpmqstguqhrhvsdvinphejfbdvrvabthpyyphyqharjvzriosrdnwmaxtgriivdqlmugtagvsoylqfwhjpmjxcysfujdvcqovxabjdbvyvembfpahvyoybdhweikcgnzrdqlzusgoobysfmlzifwjzlazuepimhbgkrfimmemhayxeqxynewcnynmgyjcwrpqnayvxoebgyjusppfpsfeonfwnbsdonucaipoafavmlrrlplnnbsaghbawooabsjndqnvruuwvllpvvhuepmqtprgktnwxmflmmbifbbsfthbeafseqrgwnwjxkkcqgbucwusjdipxuekanzwimuizqynaxrvicyzjhulqjshtsqswehnozehmbsdmacciflcgsrlyhjukpvosptmsjfteoimtewkrivdllqiotvtrubgkfcacvgqzxjmhmmqlikrtfrurltgtcreafcgisjpvasiwmhcofqkcteudgjoqqmtucnwcocsoiqtfuoazxdayricnmwcg"
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("longest_palindrome: ") { longest_palindrome(s) }
  x.report("longest_palindrome1: ") { longest_palindrome1(s) }
end

# user     system      total        real
# longest_palindrome:   0.007118   0.000000   0.007118 (  0.007215)
# longest_palindrome1:   0.433382   0.055217   0.488599 (  0.512605)
```

Comment: Consider replacing the lines from `expand = false` to the `end` statement for `if 0 < diff` with `len = p_len[mirror]; p_len[i], expand = case; when diff <= 0; [0, true]; when (len < diff) || (len == diff && i == n - 1); [len, false]; when len == diff && i < n - 1; [len, true]; else # diff < len; [diff, true]; end`. (I've assumed `p_len[mirror]` is defined and not expensive to calculate  when `diff <= 0`, where it's not needed).

Comment: You may wish to include @Benji's method in your benchmark. I intend to examine Manacher's algorithm in detail if I can do so without getting a migraine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, using less features of Ruby and iteration instead of recursion:

```
def longest_palindrome(string)
  # to find the longest palindrome, start with whole thing
  substr_start = 0
  substr_length = string.length
  while substr_length > 0 # 1 is a trivial palindrome and the end case
#    puts 'substr_length is:' + substr_length.to_s
    while substr_start <= string.length - substr_length
#      puts 'start is: ' + substr_start.to_s
      if palindrome?(string.slice(substr_start,substr_length))
        puts 'found palindrome: ' + string.slice(substr_start,substr_length)
        return string.slice(substr_start,substr_length)
      end
      substr_start += 1
    end
    substr_start = 0 # inner loop ctr reset
    substr_length -= 1
  end
  puts 'null string tested?'
  return ''
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a more readable:

```
def longest_palindrome(s)
  longest = s[0]
  length = s.length
  length.times do |index|
    (length - index).times do |end_index|
      candidate = s[index..(index + end_index)]
      longest = candidate if palindrom?(candidate) && candidate.length > longest.length
    end
  end
  longest
end

def palindrom? word
    (word.length/2).times do |index|
        if (word[index]!=word[word.length-index-1])
            return false
        end
    end
    return true
end
```

And a more optimal solution:

```
def longest_palindrome(s)
  longest = s[0]
  length = s.length
  length.times do |index|
    (length - index).times do |length_to_examine|
      next if longest.length > length_to_examine
      is_palindrom = true
      ((length_to_examine+1)/2).times do |to_examine|
        if (s[index+to_examine]!=s[index + length_to_examine - to_examine])
          is_palindrom = false
          break
        end
      end
      next if !is_palindrom || length_to_examine < longest.length
      longest = s[index..(index+length_to_examine)]
    end
  end
  longest
end
```

Comment: Can you provide more text to describe your code?

Answer (score -1):

This is a ruby implementation of the naive/slow solution proposed in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring)

```
def PalindromicSubstring(str)
  # slow algorithm O(n^2)
  bogus_chars = str.size.times.map { "|" }
  odd_str = str.chars.zip(bogus_chars).flatten.unshift("|").join
  str_size = odd_str.size
  longest_radius_by_center = Array.new(str_size, 0)

  str_size.times do |center|
    radius = 0
    radius += 1 while center - (radius + 1) >= 0 && center + radius + 1 < str_size && odd_str[center - (radius + 1)] == odd_str[center + radius + 1]
    longest_radius_by_center[center] = radius
  end

  max_longest_radius = longest_radius_by_center.max
  center_for_max_longest_radius = longest_radius_by_center.index max_longest_radius

  start_index = center_for_max_longest_radius - max_longest_radius
  end_index = center_for_max_longest_radius + max_longest_radius

  longest_palindrome = odd_str[start_index..end_index].tr("|", "")
  longest_palindrome.size > 2 ? longest_palindrome : "none"
end
```

This is the Manacher's algorithm

```
def PalindromicSubstring(str)
  # Manacher's algorithm O(n)
  bogus_chars = str.size.times.map { "|" }
  odd_str = str.chars.zip(bogus_chars).flatten.unshift("|").join
  str_size = odd_str.size
  longest_radius_by_center = Array.new(str_size, 0)

  center = 0
  while center < str_size
    radius = 0

    radius += 1 while center - (radius + 1) >= 0 && center + radius + 1 < str_size && odd_str[center - (radius + 1)] == odd_str[center + radius + 1]

    longest_radius_by_center[center] = radius

    old_center = center
    old_radius = radius
    center += 1
    radius = 0
    while center <= old_center + old_radius
      mirrored_center = old_center - (center - old_center)
      max_mirrored_radius = old_center + old_radius - center

      if longest_radius_by_center[mirrored_center] < max_mirrored_radius
        longest_radius_by_center[center] = longest_radius_by_center[mirrored_center]
        center += 1
      elsif longest_radius_by_center[mirrored_center] > max_mirrored_radius
        longest_radius_by_center[center] = max_mirrored_radius
        center += 1
      else
        radius = max_mirrored_radius 
        break
      end
    end
  end

  max_longest_radius = longest_radius_by_center.max
  center_for_max_longest_radius = longest_radius_by_center.index(max_longest_radius)

  start_index = center_for_max_longest_radius - max_longest_radius
  end_index = center_for_max_longest_radius + max_longest_radius

  longest_palindrome = odd_str[start_index..end_index].tr("|", "")
  longest_palindrome.size > 2 ? longest_palindrome : "none"
end
```

Any suggestions on how to do it more the ruby way?