# How to check that a string has a sub string(min 3 char) is a palindrome using regular expressions and get that sub string?

Tags: ruby, string, palindrome

I have a string and need to extract all palindrome substrings (minimum length is 3 characters) using **regular expression**

Is this possible?

I want a solution like below

```
str = "abcbd"
puts sub_str_palindrome(str)
# output 
["bcb"]

str = "abcde"
puts sub_str_palindrome(str)
# output 
[]
```

Comment: Hard to give an answer when you haven’t given your full desired outputs. What if there are multiple palindromes? Do you want all of them, the longest, the shortest?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby - Finding the longest palindromic substring in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769455/ruby-finding-the-longest-palindromic-substring-in-a-string)

Comment: Please, share more details. Do you need to look for the first palindrome of length 3, if it's not present - try 4, and so forth until you check the whole string?

Comment: @ChaseMcDougall yes i need all of them if got multiple palindromes

Answer (score 0):

Here are some clues for regexp
to match 3-4 characters palindrome:

```
(.)(.)\2?\1
```

5-6 characters (add `(?:(.)\3?\2|` and `)` after `\2?`:

```
(.)(.)(?:(.)\3?\2|\2?)\1
```

7-8 characters (add `(?:(.)\4?\3|` and `)` after `\3?`):

```
(.)(.)(?:(.)(?:(.)\4?\3|\3?)\2|\2?)\1
```

etc.

I hope this algorithm will help you to implement the method